# EKS HPA: unable to fetch metrics from API: the server could not find the requested resource (get pods.metrics.k8s.io)

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

I am using EKS and bitnami metrics server [helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/metrics-server).

The HPA resource shows the following message: failed to get cpu utilization: unable to get metrics for resource cpu: no metrics returned from resource metrics API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing the helm chart metrics server installation and installing metrics-server the eks way using the manifest in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/metrics-server.html)